# How to convert between Kunitz units and Enzymatic units?

Tags: enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

I've googled around and there has been the common answer of 1.5 U = 1 Kunitz Unit, but none of those answers have come from a reputable source, so I am really doubtful. :(

The enzyme I use comes in 723 Kunitz units per mg protein, but I need 600 U per mg of DNA being used in my procedure. I do not know how to properly determine how many Kunitz units equivocate to Enzymatic Units, and vice versa.